# Is Sitecore's Managed Cloud is PCI compliant?

Tags: sitecore-managed-cloud

Does anyone know if Sitecore's Managed Cloud is PCI compliant and to what level?

I haven't found any documentation on it, so I am assuming no, unless it can be requested when purchased.

Answer (score 0):

As Sitecore Managed Cloud is just an additional service on top of Azure, you have PCI compliance same as Azure. Please check the below references.

https://www.sitecore.com/trust/resources

https://www.sitecore.com/-/media/sitecoresite/files/home/trust-center/managed_cloud_security_overview.pdf?md=20210826T132834Z

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/compliance/offerings/offering-pci-dss

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/compliance/offerings/offering-pci-3ds

https://www.espire.com/blog/posts/sitecore-managed-cloud-drive-digital-experiences-at-scale-with-cloud